# Does rotting surface near window relate to ant problem?

Tags: walls, paint, ants

I just moved to an (rented) apartment in a big urban building, and there’s an ant problem that seems to be coming from one particular window. Right next to that window is what looks like rotting paint, or some kind of rotting surface. The ants also seem to be coming from the wall itself next to where that rotting paint is.

That’s also the window where an air conditioner unit was previously installed, so I don’t know if the rotting is related to the moisture from that. Can this rotting stuff be related to the ants coming from there? And is the rotting or whatever it is dangerous or bad in any way?

It’s a rent-stabilized building that isn’t really into intensive maintenance, but if I can hire someone who says there’s a real issue I’m sure they’ll be responsive. I’m happy to ignore it, I just don’t know if it’s an issue.

[image]

[image: Window with rot]

[image: Rot]

[image: Window corner with ants]

[image: Floor under window where ants come through]

Comment: It looks like two separate problems.  The outside is a water damage problem up to the building owners to take care of.  The ants you can try pest control yourself or get the pest professionals in.  It might not be just your apartment but others beside you that have the problem also.  Doing just your place might only stop the ants for a few days.  Will also need to know the type of ants and make sure they are not termites/carpenter ants that do damage to the building.

Comment: Is the outside thing a dangerous thing or a problem?

Comment: get some roach power, boric acid. It will kill both the mold and ants. if the AC is gone, the mold likely won't come back. The boric acid can be mixed with honey or bacon grease to eradicate a building-wide infestation in a few weeks; look for "recipes" on the web.

Comment: The water and the ants are probably related. Ants love to live in wet wood areas. This isn't a quick problem or a big one - you can use ant powder to paste over it and then have someone in to take a look at the water issues.

Answer (score 1):

If they are carpenter ants, they may be eating their way through the wood, contributing to the damage caused by discharge from the former AC installed here. If they're "regular" ants, they are likely just finding their way through holes that have been rotted out by the regular drip of moisture from the AC unit. The ants may also be coming from neighbors apartments *in addition* to coming in through this opening. You can put down traps or chemicals to kill the ants, but you may be facing an ongoing battle, as new ants will come to replace the now dead ones.

You're right that there's not much you can do about the structural issue in the window frame - you have to get building maintenance to do that work (whether they do it or contract it out is up to them). Building maintenance *should* be interested in protecting the building, however, as you've noted, it's rent-controlled, so the owners may not be making a lot of profit on it, so it may, unfortunately, be lower on their maintenance list.

If this continues without response from management and becomes unlivable for you, you may ultimately have to get the city health department and or building commission involved in forcing the owner's hand in making repairs. Note that this may have other consequences - they can't raise your rent, but they might not renew your lease and may become unresponsive to other maintenance requests.

A less "nuclear" option might be to simply apply some caulk to the inside to plug up the holes to keep ants and moisture out and keep air from flowing through - heat out in the summer, heat in in the winter. This isn't a "proper" fix and not one you should do on your own property, but it is a stop-gap measure that may be workable if the building owner just isn't responding.